# Iterate through parameters skipping the first

Tags: bash

Hi i have the following:

```
bash_script parm1 a b c d ..n
```

I want to iterate and print all the values in the command line starting from a, not from parm1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove first element from $@ in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701400/remove-first-element-from-in-bash)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#ignore first parm1
shift

# iterate
while test ${#} -gt 0
do
  echo $1
  shift
done
```

Comment: ecelletn thanx :)
what does -gt do ?
Sorry I know to lazy to google

Comment: greater than. just a comparison operator for test :-)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty lazy. Try `help test` which is only 9 characters and a <return>. Good luck.

Answer (score 154):

You can "slice" arrays in bash; instead of using `shift`, you might use

```
for i in "${@:2}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

`$@` is an array of all the command line arguments, `${@:2}` is the same array less the first element. The double-quotes ensure correct whitespace handling.

Comment: Be careful, as slicing may cause problems with whitespace in e.g. globbed paths. The file `folder/my file` will be split to `folder/my` and `file` if invoked as `./script.sh folder/*`. The accepted answer using `shift` and `$1` works as intended in this case.

Comment: @jkgeyti This isn't a problem with globbed paths, just a problem with whitespace handling. Properly quoting like `for i in "${@:2}"; do echo "$i"; done` fixes that issue.

Comment: Could someone edit the quotes into the answer? I'd have almost missed the comment that fixes the whitespace issue.

Answer (score 10):

Another flavor, a bit shorter that keeps the arguments list

```
shift
for i in "$@"
do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: (You might also change `echo $i` to `echo "$i"` -- that way `./yourscript '*'` actually prints `*`, not a list of files; it also means that `./yourscript $'argument\twith\ttabs'` actually prints tabs, instead of having them changed to spaces).

Answer (score 9):

This method will keep the first param, in case you want to use it later

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=2;i<=$#;i++))
do
  echo ${!i}
done
```

or

```
for i in ${*:2} #or use $@
do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: @logicor, it's an indirect expansion -- it looks up the value of the variable whose name is in the variable `i`.

Comment: BTW, `"${@:2}"` is certainly more correct than `${*:2}`. Describing them as alternatives is rather off-the-mark.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an implicit iteration for the positional parameters:

```
shift
for arg
do
    something_with $arg
done
```

As you can see, you don't have to include `"$@"` in the `for` statement.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: fixed