# Operating on pairs of (first+subsequent) arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script whose first parameter is an identifier for an object to which every subsequent parameter will be compared.

I know how to use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to refer to individual parameters, but how can I store the value of the first and then loop over everything *but* the first?

Comment: No matter what else your script contains, the shebang MUST be the first line in the script to be effective.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, of course it has to be. I accidentally put it into the code line.

Comment: Eh? `exec` is a builtin that replaces the shell with the command being run. Nothing after it will ever be run in the same shell if it succeeds (since that shell will no longer be in memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is a simple extension to [Iterate through parameters skipping the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575793/iterate-through-parameters-skipping-the-first) (the only difference being the need to store the first argument before discarding it).

Use `shift` to pop an argument off the list so you can iterate over the rest. Thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
first=$1; shift || exit
for arg; do
  echo "Using first argument $first with additional argument $arg"
done
```

If you run this script with `./theScript argA argB argC`, you'll get the following output:

```
Using first argument argA with additional argument argB
Using first argument argA with additional argument argC
```

...which, as best I can tell, is the behavior you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Mind if I try to edit the question to be more clearly asking the thing this is an answer to? I had to make some leaps of intuition to get here. :)

Comment: Of course not, please feel free to do so and thank you!