# Ruby for loop starting with the second function parameter

Tags: bash

How can I iterate over my function parameters starting with the second parameter?

```
#!/bin/bash -

function test23() {
  echo 'hello world'

  for text in $2..$@
  do
   echo $text
   done
}

test23 start with the second argument
```

My current output is

```
hello world
with..start
with
the
second
argument
```

and I want to get 'with the second argument'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per stack-overflow: [Iterate through parameters skipping the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575793/iterate-through-parameters-skipping-the-first)

```
function test23() {
  echo 'hello world'
  for text in "${@:2}"; do
    echo $text
  done
}

$ test23 start with the second argument
hello world
with
the
second
argument
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `shift`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test23() {
  echo 'hello world'

  shift

  for text
  do
    printf '%s\n' "$text"
  done
}
```